# Translating a batch with java commands for xml to C#

Tags: c#, java, xml, cmd

I currently have a batch file with this line:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java" -Xmx1224m -classpath .\xalan.jar 
org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process -IN  FileIn.xml -XSL FileConvert.xslt -OUT FileOut.xml
```

It takes an given `xml` and a given `xslt` and spits out a new, converted `xml`. The batch runs just fine, but I'm trying to translate this into `C#` so that I can build an application around it and have the ability to change some parameters, like which input files to select.

My code is this,

```
ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", 
        "/k " + "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre7\\bin\\java\" -Xmx1224m -classpath .\xalan.jar org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process -IN  In.xml -XSL Convert.xslt -OUT Out.xml");
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
proc.Start();
```

thinking it would run like a simple `CMD` command. When I do this, I just get a message with a list of the Java commands you are allowed to use and it quits out there. I've tried a few variations of using the quotations, like `@"C:\...` and so forth.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you build that application in Java instead?

Comment: I was handed this batch from someone else who created it a while ago. They are no longer around. I'm most familiar with C#, which is the only reason I am trying.

Comment: If you have Batch file... then Why don't you call that Batch file by C#...?

Comment: I've though about doing that. I want to be able to change which files it takes in, and the name of the file it spits out. I could read the batch, change the names, or just create the string and write it to a batch, then run it.. but that seems repetitive if I can just do it in the code, doesn't it? Maybe that's the best way..

Comment: Batch files can accept input parameters. See http://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below, It will be help you...

```
string commandLine = "-Xmx1224m -classpath .\xalan.jar org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process -IN  In.xml -XSL Convert.xslt -OUT Out.xml";
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(commandLine);
procStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java";
procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
proc.Start();
string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(result);
```